# What is the view between domestic and foreign prospective PhD students (U.S)?

Tags: phd

So in my CS Ph.D. applications, in addition to the required Statement of Purpose (for everyone), domestic students are required to submit a Personal Statement. (Why?)

Q1: Are domestic applicants considered differently in terms of the review process? Is it more "costly" for the institutions to acquire a foreign than domestic students?

Q2: While most foreign students (from India & China, etc.) are elites, are there any tradeoffs when it comes to competing against domestic US students?  or are they equal footing?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Huh? Which departments/universities are asking for this?

Comment: University of California, Irvine (Computer Science / Informatics / Software Engineering)

Comment: Again: Huh? [This UCI ICS web site](https://www.ics.uci.edu/grad/admissions/Prospective_ApplicationProcess.php) lists the application materials, including “Personal Statement (same as Statement of Purpose)”. [I have a master’s degree in CS from Irvine.]

Comment: Statement of Purpose (required)

then in the next section,

Personal History Statement (Required for US Citizens, US Permanent Residents, and DACA eligible applicants)

Comment: It's not a "personal statement", it is a "personal *history* statement", a UC-specific thing that's basically a diversity statement.

Comment: I see... so does it have any effect on the decision?  Why don't foreigners require it?  Advantage?

Comment: Foreign students are not counted as members of ethnic or racial minority groups for purposes of affirmative action and diversity programs.